# How to update Netbeans projects view?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using netbeans 8.0.2 and I want to update my projects view tree. When I create a web service client, Netbeans adds a second "Web Pages" element to my projects view.

- Web Pages
- Web Pages(/src)

Is there a way to hide second Web Pages element?

[image]

Comment: i see only one "Web Pages" folder

Comment: @FastSnail Screenshot is not my project's view but an example image to show which panel I mean :)

Comment: Not sure, but might be related to these netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=240799 and netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242064 that I stumbled into recently. They are marked as resolved but I think I have a live example now. (Sorry for remove/re-comment, I looked at the screenshot, figured I had misunderstood and removed my comment, then read the text again. That said, can you create a new screenshot and just censor any sensitive info? The current one is really misleading.)

Answer (score 0):

IMO this might be related to these bug reports that are marked as closed but I have seen live in Netbeans 8.1 and 8.2:

- https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=240799
- https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242064

To check if this is the case:

1. Look in your pom file and see if you have a `<webResources>` section, most likely in a `maven-war-plugin` in your pom-file.
2. If you see it, try temporarily removing it, saving the file and see if the second "Web Pages(/src)" disappears, it should disappear immediately if you are seeing the same issue as I saw.

If this is your issue, see if you can somehow get rid of that `<webResources>` section by putting stuff in the default locations.